# How to store class definition of dynamically generated java class using ASM?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, dynamic-class-creation

I extended a class dynamically using ASM. I used defineClass method without ProtectionDomain argument.When I try to use that class in other class, I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFound Error. How can I store or retrieve class definition which is defined runtime using ASM ?

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, your best bet is to post the problematic code as a [mcve] with a good description of what/where it goes wrong. Without any code, your question becomes far too broad.

Comment: This isnt what was intended in your question .. You must put the exact requirements and problem which you were facing for. You intended to ask for noClassDefFoundError for which a solution was provided.

Comment: Will be more specific with my question next time. Your code snippet helped me immensely to resolve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating DynamicClassLoader Instance each time, storing it in class level static variable solves this issue. Each time new class loader was being created so previously created class wasn't found.